# Get one of the possible value of a Brush in UWP app

Tags: c#, .net, win-universal-app

I'm doing an UWP application. One of my UserControl have a dependency property that is a `SolidColorBrush`.

In WPF, I've the following:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty BackgroundColorProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("BackgroundColor", typeof(SolidColorBrush), typeof(StarControl),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((SolidColorBrush)Brushes.Transparent,
            new PropertyChangedCallback(OnBackgroundColorChanged)));
```

For now, in UWP, I've the following:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty BackgroundColorProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("BackgroundColor", typeof(SolidColorBrush), typeof(StarControl),new PropertyMetadata(/* ?????*/, OnBackgroundColorChanged));
```

The issue is that `Brushes` doesn't seems to be available, what should be used?

Thank you

Comment: Are you setting the property in XAML or by code?

Comment: @TomDroste The issue is about how to set the default value(`/ ?????*/` in my code) of the DP in the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `Brushes` equivalent in UWP. Create a SolidColorBrush from one of the static values in the `Colors` class.

```
DependencyProperty.Register(
    "BackgroundColor", typeof(SolidColorBrush), typeof(StarControl),
    new PropertyMetadata(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent), OnBackgroundColorChanged));
```

---

Besides that, your property should not be called `BackgroundColor` when it actually is a Brush, so better call it `BackgroundBrush`.

Comment: But in WPF, all possible color have a singleton `Brush` available in `Brushes` static class, for performance reason(no need to instantiate another one for every time we use a Brush). There is nothing like it in UWP?

Comment: In my knowledge that is what the Colors aspect is, but then for colors. I don't know if there is a equivalent for the SolidColorBrush. You could create your own singleton for it.